# How can I speed up my 3 wings fan?

Tags: fans

I am using a 3 wings fan in my house and it works very slow, so i want to make it fast and it also do not contain any capacitor or a cylinder type small device.it's an old fan

Comment: Did you have a question? Replace the thing.

Comment: You could try taking the fan down and cleaning it. Clean the motor with electric parts cleaner. Make sure it spins freely. Maybe oil /grease the shaft / bearings or whatever it has. But, like others have said, the motor seems to be dying. I doubt you'll see much improvement and you could make it worse.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the fan motor is dying.  Sadly, nothing lasts forever.  The more expensive units can be repaired, but it sounds like you have a cheaper model that isn't made to be repairable.

Luckily, cheap ceiling fans are pretty affordable.  Mine cost under $40.

Time to replace it.